# Value data and Count data in two separate columns - I'd like to get one column of Frequency data

Tags: r, frequency

I have observations in Value and Count form (frequency information)

value<- c(0,1,3,6,7,8)
count <-c (3,2,1,1,1,3)

I want the data ("value") in one column, where I have 3 counts of 0, and 2 counts of 1, one count of 3 etc. 
I want all of my raw values in one column. Like this:

freq_of_values <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8)

```
value<- c(0,1,3,6,7,8)
count <- c(3,2,1,1,1,3)
```

I've searched and tried the (dplyr) merge and sort functions but am not getting what I want. Perhaps my terminology while searching wasn't just right. Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Another option is `uncount`: `library(tidyr); uncount(data.frame(value, count), count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rep` with `times` as 'count' vector

```
rep(value, times = count)
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 3 6 7 8 8 8
```

---

If the initial data is `data.frame`

```
 df1 <- data.frame(value, count)
```

create a new data.frame with

```
df2 <- data.frame(freq_of_values = rep(df1$value, df1$count))
```

---

Or using `uncount` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
uncount(df1, count) %>%
   rename(freq_of_values = value) %>%
   as_tibble
```

Comment: and then convert it to a data.frame: `as.data.frame(result)`

Comment: Thanks, Akrun! That's exactly what I need!